# Trying to tag doctrine data fixtures with _instanceof only for 'test' env in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine, autowired, instanceof

I'm coding a Symfony 4.1 rest API and trying to use fixtures to setup the test database for my phpunit tests.

My issue is that I would like to have fixtures that run based on the symfony env, by providing the `-e test` option to the `doctrine:fixtures:load` command

After reading some doc I was thinking about using the symfony autowiring _instanceof functionnality and also the `services_test.yaml` file, but it does not seem to work.

If I move the `_instanceof` bit of code into `services.yaml`, it works, but for all envs of course.

Does anyone have an idea ? Maybe I've missed something. Thanks in advance for your suggestions :)

Here's what I've done :

## The interface used for tagging

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

interface BookieTestFixtureInterface
{
}
```

## The 'test-only' fixture

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class UserFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements BookieTestFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

## The services_test.yaml file

```
services:
    _defaults:
        public: true

    _instanceof:
        App\DataFixtures\BookieTestFixtureInterface:
            tags: ['doctrine.fixture.orm']
```

## The services.yaml file

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true     
        autoconfigure: true 
        public: false

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

## Solution (services_test.yaml)

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true

    _instanceof:
        App\DataFixtures\BookieTestFixtureInterface:
            tags: ['doctrine.fixture.orm']

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `_instanceof` applies only to the current file. So you need to PSR-4 autodiscover fixtures in `services_test.yaml`:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        public: true

    _instanceof:
        App\DataFixtures\BookieTestFixtureInterface:
            tags: ['doctrine.fixture.orm']

    App\:
        resource: '../src/Fixtures'
```

Let me know how it works.

---

There is also a similar question regarding the scope of `_instanceof` under the [release post on Symfony blog](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-simpler-service-configuration#comment-21154), but with no response.

Comment: Well thanks a lot ! It was indeed the right solution, I just had to add a little more configuration otherwise it was not passing the ObjectManager to my fixture. I'm going to edit my question with the full solution.